# Un Script que me muestre una pantalla u otra según el dispositivo que la visite

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirección

Quiero hacer una pantalla con una imagen y un botón de Download en el centro de la misma. Y quiero que esta pantalla se vea bien tanto en pc como en smartphone, pero no quiero usar el responsive. Quiero que esto se haga a través de un script que me detecte si el que visita la web es un smartphone o si es un pc. Y como siempre uso el responsive no se como se podría hacer esto.
¿Alguien tiene algún script por ahi que pueda usar?

Lo que más me interesaría, sería que el visitante fuera redirigido hacia una versión o hacia otra con un pequeño script con muy poco código. Un mobile redirect que lo lleve hacia donde corresponda.

Comment: Yo tengo un script pero funciona con php. Nose si te servira

Comment: ¿Y tienes la parte de html donde se referencian las imágenes? O hay que poner en el php una imagen u otra según el dispositivo? si es así en que parte se pone, Mas allá de formularios el php no me entero.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, tendrias que hacer varios archivos, cada uno con una imagen distinta para pc o movil y poner el nombre de ese archivo aqui `include('nombre_archivo');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber si se trata de un smartphone con javascript (sacado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/1468942)):

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;
```

Y para redirigir:

```
// como si fuera un redirect HTTP -- Esta es la más probable que necesitas
window.location.replace("http://es.stackoverflow.com");

// como si se hiciera un click a un link
window.location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
```

Alternativamente puedes consultar (en lugar de mirar si se trata de un móvil) el `width` total de la pantalla con `screen.width` que te devuelve el width máximo de la pantalla del cliente.

Comment: Alguien ha quitado su +1 y ha puesto su -1; Podría saber el por qué? Si es un fallo en la respuesta me gustaría solucionarlo.

Comment: Yo he quitado el visto bueno a la respuesta de Alberto y te he dado el visto bueno a ti por que tu respuesta es más fiel a la idea que yo tenía de lo que quería hacer. No se quien te ha quitado un punto. Yo os había dado un punto a cada uno y ahora me aparece a cero. tampoco lo entiendo.

Comment: @MarcLemien Alguien a quién no le debe haber gustado el cambio de respuesta quizá. He intentado analizar lo mejor posible pero da igual. Gracias marc!

Comment: No sabemos... porque aquí cualquier puede subir y bajar puntos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo este script en php nose si puedes usarlo o tiene que ser en javascript. Te dejo el código por si acaso:

```
    /**************************SCRIPT VALIDAR SI ES UN MOVIL, TABLET...****************************************/

$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;
$body_class = 'desktop';

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])))
{
    $tablet_browser++;
    $body_class = "tablet";
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    $body_class = "mobile";
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']))))
{
    $mobile_browser++;
    $body_class = "mobile";
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents))
{
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0)
{
    $mobile_browser++;
    //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
    $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua))
    {
      $tablet_browser++;
  }
}


/*************************************FIN SCRIPT***************************************/
```

EDICIÓN

```
if ($tablet_browser > 0)
{
    include('nombre_del_archivo_para_tablet.html');
}
else if($mobile_browser > 0)
{
    include('nombre_del_archivo_para_movil.html');
}
else
{
    include('nombre_del_archivo_para_pc.html');
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Buena respuesta! Creo que el array de mobile-agents es un poco más corto que el que he propuesto en mi respuesta, quieres hacer un edit añadiendo los que te faltan? un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @AlbertoMier no me gusta mucho el php pero esa no es razón para que tu código no sea bueno. Lo es!, pero la respuesta de Miquel Coll se acerca más a lo que buscaba. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo buscaba en realidad era más algo como esto:
Esto me detecta que anchura tiene el dispositivo que lo visita y entonces me redirige el usuario hacía una web o hacía otra.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi el...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Me ha dejado de funcionar; ahora empleo

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var dispositivo = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if( dispositivo.search(/iphone|ipod|ipad|android/) > -1 ){
document.location = "https://www.midominio.com/celular.html"; }
</script>
```

Y funciona perfectamente, además m.domain.com parece ser un subdominio seguramente creado para celulares con acceso mediante httaccess.

En mi web empleo prioritariamente html y css; php sólo para contadores de visitas y formularios.